# I want to edit and delete record in my sqlite database but each time i click on edit button and delete button application crashes

Tags: java

Error message is that it could not found colum  for my object.
Here is my code:

```
db.exeSql("UPDATE table_foods SET='"+name.getText()+"',"+price +"='"+price. getText() +"'Where food_id="+I'd. getText() +"")
db.execSQL(Delete FROM table_foods Where foods_id=' "+I'd. getText() +" ' ")
```

Comment: what kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: check your `'` and `"` at first glance they look out of sync